# viewAppointment() missing 1 required positional argument: 'appointment_id'

Tags: python, django, database

while running my code i have encountered this kind of error which is i dont know how it happened

this is my views.py

```
def viewAppointment(request, appointment_id):
appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(id=appointment_id)

return render(request, 'appointment_form.html', {'Appointment': appointment})
```

this is urls.py

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views
app_name = "Project"

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index , name='index'),
   path('counter', views.counter, name='counter'),
   path('Register', views.Register, name= 'Register'),
   path('login', views.login, name='login'),
   path('logout', views.logout, name = 'logout'),
   path('post/<str:pk>', views.post, name = 'post'),
   path('appointment', views.viewAppointment, name='appointment'),
   re_path(r'^appointment/appointment=(?P<appointment_id>[0-100]+)/AddDiagnonsis', 
   views.addDiagnosis, name='AddDiagnosis')
   ]
```

Comment: `path('appointment', views.viewAppointment, name='appointment'),` this appears to only pass one argument, but your definition requires 2: `def viewAppointment(request, appointment_id):`

Comment: so what do i have to add ?

Comment: Your definition is looking for `request` and `appointment_id`; you are passing in a `name`... so either put `request` and `appointment_id` in directly, or instead call a wrapper method in `path()` that will take the `name`, determine `request`+`appointment_id` and then call `viewAppointment()`

Comment: and can you teach me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your function need an extra argument, the appointment_id, you must to include it on the url:

```
path('appointment/<str:pk>', views.viewAppointment, name='appointment'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the response bro, but i receive  a "Page not found (404)" error  it say's Not Found: /appointment

Comment: Of course... you must to add the id on the url. Like this: yourdomain.com/appointment/1 (or the id of the appointment you want to show)

Comment: how can i do that bro ? can you teach me ?

Comment: domain like my local host  ?